# how to solve scrollbar overlay over elements

Tags: sass, vuejs2

I'm participating in a project with Vue2, in which I'm creating a component that can contain several cards. I put the parent component's overflow to overlay.

```css
overflow: overlay;
```

I'm hiding the scrollbar when the mouse leaves the element putting a class if this happens

```html
<div 
  @mouseenter="() => moreOneChild && hideScroll(false)"
  @mouseleave="() => moreOneChild && hideScroll(true)"
>
```

```js
export default {
    data: () => ({
      hideOverflowBlocks: true,
      hideOverflowModules: true
    })
    
    computed: {
     moreOneChild() {
       return this.childrenShowOnBlock.length > 1
     },
    }
    
    methods: { 
      hideScroll(show, name = 'Modules') {
        this[`hideOverflow${name}`] = show
      }
    }
}
```

Being that sometimes he ends up getting behind the cards as in the image below

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

I've tried everything. put the `z-index` of the scrollbar to be bigger than the card I tried to put it to disappear using `display: hidden` and `display: none`. But I was not successful

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it using `clip-path` css from [another question](https://I%20managed%20to%20solve%20it%20using%20clip-path%20css%20from%20another%20question%20here%20in%20the%20community.) here in the community.

```scss
.module-content {
  //...
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);

  &.hide-overflow {
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: hidden;
    }
  }
```

tanks [Kirill Simonov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8629960/kirill-simonov)

Comment: Oi Gerson! Could you please put a link to that "another question"? The one there is pointing to https://i%20managed%20to%20solve%20it%20using%20clip-path%20css%20from%20another%20question%20here%20in%20the%20community./, which is the text of the whole sentence.